# acces z axis of Axes3DSubplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to modify the label of my 3D plot on the z-axis, here is my code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

x.ticklabel_format(style = 'sci', axis = 'z', scilimits = (0, 2))

offset = ax.get_zaxis().get_offset_text()
text = offset.get_text()
offset.set_visible(False)

ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z ' + text)
```

If I use `get_yaxis()` instead of `get_zaxis()` it works. With `get_zaxis()` I get the error: 
    AttributeError: 'Axes3DSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_zaxis'

How can I access the z-axis in the same manner?

Comment: works fine for me but the docs say "New in version 1.1.0: This function was added, but not tested. Please report any bugs."

Comment: I created a [pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11385) to add a `get_zaxis()` method into matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

No, there doesn't appear to be the equivalent function. However, you can just access the `zaxis` using `ax.zaxis` instead of `ax.get_zaxis()`.

So you should be able to use this line of code:

```
offset = ax.zaxis.get_offset_text()
```